# Create line object - Matrix vs. vector input

Tags: matlab, line, matlab-figure

Why is there a difference between

```
figure;
process = {'process' , [0.2500 0.5000], [0.6 0.8];
           'process2', [0.1250 0.2500], [0.2 0.6];
           'process3', [0.3125 0.2500], [0.4 0.6];
           'process4', [0.2500 0.3125], [0.2 0.4];
           'process5', [0.3750 0.3125], [0.2 0.4];
           'process5', [0.5625 0.5000], [0.6 0.8];};  
L=line(cell2mat(process(:,2)), cell2mat(process(:,3)));
```

and

```
figure;
process = {'process' , [0.2500 0.5000], [0.6 0.8];
           'process2', [0.1250 0.2500], [0.2 0.6];
           'process3', [0.3125 0.2500], [0.4 0.6];
           'process4', [0.2500 0.3125], [0.2 0.4];
           'process5', [0.3750 0.3125], [0.2 0.4];
           'process5', [0.5625 0.5000], [0.6 0.8];};
hold on
L=line(cell2mat(process(1,2)), cell2mat(process(1,3)));
L=line(cell2mat(process(2,2)), cell2mat(process(2,3)));
L=line(cell2mat(process(3,2)), cell2mat(process(3,3)));
L=line(cell2mat(process(4,2)), cell2mat(process(4,3)));
L=line(cell2mat(process(5,2)), cell2mat(process(5,3)));
L=line(cell2mat(process(6,2)), cell2mat(process(6,3)));
```

?

[image]

Is there a way that enables me to use the first version (= using the line function only once) with the result of the second one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the documentation for [line](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/line.html):

```
line(X,Y) adds the line defined in vectors X and Y to the
current axes. If X and Y are matrices of the same size, line
draws one line per column.
```

So you want,

```
line(cell2mat(process(:,2))', cell2mat(process(:,3))');
```

Comment: Well, that's it. Thanks a lot!